# How to get path of a specific file in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnkit

Is there any efficient way to get File path from SVN?

I have a path say "http://sample.com/repository/pag/branches/dev/" , under **dev** we have many folders (sub-folders under that) and files..
I know the path till **dev** .  Now, i hav to get a path of the file inside some directory under **dev** .

I tried **svn log** command and **reporting** using svnkit. but both taking more than 20 mins. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: on which platform are you doing this? are you bound to use svn cmds only for this or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will list all files under your directory, you can search for the file in there:

```
svn ls --depth infinity http://sample.com/repository/pag/branches/dev/
```

Comment: Yes.. It is taking more than 20mins to list all the files :( Thats is  my prob

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **No** efficient way...  we can either use ls , log or reporting.

These two links may help

[customized SVN depth value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859863/customized-svn-depth-value)

[How to get tree structure from SVN using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431172/how-to-get-tree-structure-from-svn-using-java)