# customized SVN depth value

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, svnkit

I need a list of all folder names under a branch in SVN. But not upto **INFINITE** depth.. Say i need upto 5 level of depth..

Is there any way to specify customized SVNdepth  value? The problem in getting a immediate folder list and iterating is, each folder contains hundreds of sub-folder.

command used :
**svn ls --depth infinity http://sample.com/repository/pag/branches/dev/**
Instead of infinity can we use customized value(numeric value)? if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately numeric depths are not supported. You should call directory listing recursively for every directory.

Comment: It is taking abt 25mins to list all directories recursively.. is there any method to  get directories efficiently?

Comment: sometimes (it depends on the repository, of course) it is faster to use depth=INFINITY and status() request of SVN remote API (see this article http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2012/07/15/subversion-remote-api-listing-repository-with-status-request/ ). If you know how to use SVNKit, it will be easy to translate that C code to Java. Note: I don't speak about "svn ls --depth=infinity" or its analogs (like SvnList class of SVNKit) which are implemented as recursive calls.

Comment: is this the only way to search for a file? Why not some other efficient way can be found?

Comment: It depends on the problem you solve. Do you want to search for a file by name? Maybe, if you know that the file has been changed recently it can be efficient to ask the log. If you know that the file is not within some directories, you may exclude them with a corresponding report... If just by name --- yes, if the repository is rather deep (otherwise recursive list/status calls with depth=IMMEDIATES could be more efficient).